# Bulk Querying AccountFeed results in Binary field not supported error

Tags: bulk-api, csv

While running the Bulk export in Java in CSV format, I get an error while the XML does not return error. I tried documentation which does not yield any results. Can I get specific error that relates to the fields?

```
[BatchInfo  xxxxx,
 state='Failed'
 stateMessage='FeatureNotEnabled : Binary field not supported'
 createdDate='java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1429194971000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=16,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=16,DAY_OF_YEAR=106,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=2,HOUR_OF_DAY=14,MINUTE=36,SECOND=11,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]'
 systemModstamp='java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1429194988000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=16,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=16,DAY_OF_YEAR=106,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=2,HOUR_OF_DAY=14,MINUTE=36,SECOND=28,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]'
 numberRecordsProcessed='0'
 numberRecordsFailed='0'
 totalProcessingTime='0'
 apiActiveProcessingTime='0'
 apexProcessingTime='0'
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message:

> FeatureNotEnabled : Binary field not supported

lead me to the [Batch failed: FeatureNotEnabled : Binary field not supported エラーについて](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000186950&language=ja) knowledge article. My first year Japanese isn't much good unless you need to count to 10. However, Google translate gave me:

> ## Description
>
> Content-related objects (ContentVersion) and attachments object (Attachment) is trying to export the data loader and the place **Batch failed: FeatureNotEnabled: Binary field not supported**  error that has occurred. Binary data is either would not be exported in data loader.
>
> ## Resolution
>
> Item type of Body item of VersionData items and Attachment object of ContentVersion object will be binary data encoded in Base64. 
>   When exporting such items via the API, but it is possible to export only in the SOAP API, and Bulk API option is enabled 
>   for the extraction of items of binary type is not supported, Batch failed: FeatureNotEnabled : Binary field not supported  is output error saying. When you export a record data via the API such as data loader will need to be exported on you disable the Bulk API option.

Reading between the translation, you can't use the Bulk API to extract the Body field from VersionData or Attachment. You will need to use the SOAP or REST APIs to extract the blob data from that field.